# winreg in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm attempting to create a small python script to add a D_WORD key into a specific location within a Windows Registry. I've read that this will require the use of _winreg.

I've used a few examples and changed it to towards what I want it to do. However, I have a few errors within this code and since I'm new to Python, I'm having issues solving them. The first is that my imports expect a colon (across the whole import statement).

Other unknown references include HKEY_LOCALE_MACHINE, EnumValue, and REG_SZ.
Any assistance with this will be greatly appreciated.

======================================================================

```
from winreg import ConnectRegistry, OpenKey, CloseKey, QueryInfoKey, SetValueEx
print r"*** Reading from SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\NetBT\Parameters ***"
aReg = winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
aKey = winreg.OpenKey(aReg, "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\NetBT\Parameters")
for i in range(winreg.QueryInfoKey(aKey)[1]):
try:
    n, v, t = EnumValue(aKey, i)
    print i, n, v, t
except EnvironmentError:
    print "Encountered problems reading the Registry..."
    break
winreg.CloseKey(aKey)
print r"*** WRiting to SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\NetBT\Parameters ***"
aKey = winreg.OpenKey(aKey, rSYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\NetBT\Parameters", 0, KEY_WRITE)
try:
    winreg.setValueEx(aKey, "SMBDeviceEnabled", 0, REG_SZ)
except EnvironmentError:
    print "Encountered problems writing into the Registry..."
winreg.CloseKey(aKey)
winreg.CloseKey(aReg)*
```

Comment: the code isn't valid Python. See the docs for the import statement.
(`for->from` is the specific error here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hacked your sample code so it will work (using python 2.7). But it doesn't look pretty. When i have some spare time i'll try to clean it up a bit.

```
import _winreg 
from _winreg import ConnectRegistry, OpenKey, CloseKey, QueryInfoKey, SetValueEx
print r"*** Reading from SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\NetBT\Parameters ***"
aReg = ConnectRegistry(None, _winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
aKey = OpenKey(aReg, "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\NetBT\Parameters")
for i in range(_winreg.QueryInfoKey(aKey)[1]):
    try:
        n, v, t = _winreg.EnumValue(aKey, i)
        print i, n, v, t
    except EnvironmentError:
        print "Encountered problems reading the Registry..."
        break
_winreg.CloseKey(aKey)
print r"*** WRiting to SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\NetBT\Parameters ***"
aKey = OpenKey(aReg, r"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\NetBT\Parameters", 0, _winreg.KEY_WRITE)
try:
    SetValueEx(aKey, "SMBDeviceEnabled", 0, _winreg.REG_SZ, "Test")
except EnvironmentError:
    print "Encountered problems writing into the Registry..."
CloseKey(aKey)
CloseKey(aReg)
```

I also suggest you have a look at: [Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/_winreg.html).

Comment: Ah thanks!!!
I'll check out the docs in a moment. Am I needed to download any third-party libraries for this to work, or is it integrated within the 2.7?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply again. I only ask because within PyCharm its still underlining all of the imports (is this something I should ignore!?)

Comment: the name of _winreg has changed in python 3.x maybe PyCharm is set tu use Python3?

Comment: Thanks for the help with this, I would up-vote this but I apparently haven't the reputation to do so. Since this may take a while to test out, you don't happen to have any experience with pyinstaller or something similar?